# How to install pem module in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, pem

I need to use a python module called pem. It can be found here: 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pem/15.0.0#downloads

I am a Windows 7 64-bit user. I use Python 2.7.

I downloaded the files from the web page. I placed the file in the C: directoy. then I opened the command line prompt and typed:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install --egg pem
```

I got this message:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pem in c:\users\xx\appd
ata\roaming\python\python27\site-packages
```

Please, help me on how to install this pem module. I can not upgrade to python 3 because of other restrictions by other modules. The pem is suppported in Python 2.7 as per the web page of the module.

**EDIT:**
Whn I tried to import pem. I get:

```
>>> import pem
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\xx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\pem\__init__.py
", line 3, in <module>
    from . import twisted
  File "C:\Users\xx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\pem\twisted.py"
, line 12, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import ssl
ImportError: No module named twisted.internet
```

Comment: It's telling you that you *already have `pem` installed*, so what's the actual problem?

Comment: @ jonrsharpe post edited.

Comment: So it would appear that the problem is `pem`'s *dependencies*, not the module itself. Have you tried to install `twisted`, too? The project's [`setup.py`](https://github.com/hynek/pem/blob/master/setup.py#L86) claims it doesn't need any external packages (and the PyPI page says it *"has no dependencies"*), but maybe try installing from [`dev-requirements.txt`](https://github.com/hynek/pem/blob/master/dev-requirements.txt), which includes `twisted`. You could also consider raising an Issue on the project's GitHub page.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

> pip install pem

It worked for me.